# Regular expression , must end with comma

Tags: .net, regex, c#-4.0, mips

I'm trying to parse instructions passed in. I want to use regex to validate each substring.
How can I make sure a string ends with a comma?  My regex for memory(mips) is also not working.

```
public static OperandType GetRegisterType(this string source)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(source, @"\$t[0-9]"))
                return OperandType.Temporary; // $t0 - $t9
            if (Regex.IsMatch(source, @"\$s[0-9]"))
                return OperandType.Store; // $s0 - $s9
            if (Regex.IsMatch(source, @"\$k[0-1]"))
                return OperandType.OSReserved; // $k0 - $k1
            if (Regex.IsMatch(source, @"[-+]?\b\d+\b"))
                return OperandType.Constant;
            if (Regex.IsMatch(source, @"\$zero"))
                return OperandType.Special;
            if (Regex.IsMatch(source, @"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b\:"))
                return OperandType.Label;
            if (Regex.IsMatch(source, @"\d+\b\(\$[s-t]\b[0-9])"))
                return OperandType.Memory;
            return OperandType.Invalid;

        }
```

example of how to load from memory

```
lw $t7,248($t2)
```

Comment: Why do you need Regex? source.EndsWith(",") would do what you want and is nice and readable.

Comment: I need to make sure the entire string fits a form. i.e temporary => $t0 - $t9

Comment: Pleae explain what you mean by *How can I make sure a string ends with a comma?* as your example `lw $t7,248($t2)` doesn't have a comma at the end.

Comment: @Borodin every operand will end with comma except the last . In that example there are only 2 operands, lw is considers operator and handle differently

Comment: Then I think you should use `String.Split` to split the operand string at the commas and verify each piece separately.

Comment: @Borodin at the point that this method the operands have be slit already and are passed in seperately. I decided to do as you suggested and check if it ends with commma before passing to GetRegisterType(). Thanks

Comment: @atbyrd Ah OK. So they have already been split at the commas, but the commas are still in the operands? Strange. But there's no need to check for commas as the split has already done that: all you need to do is allow for an optional trailing comma at the end of each operand by adding `,?` resulting in `@"^\$t[0-9],?$"` etc.

Comment: @Borodin I actually use whitespace as the delimiter, that's why the comma remains.

Comment: @Borodin u can view the source at https://bitbucket.org/atbyrd/mips-scanner/src/6bddb5b15dcc/mips-syntax if you still interested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean about a string ending with a comma. As far as I can tell you can just write `@"\$t[0-9],"`.

Your memory regex doesn't match because you have `[s-t]\b[0-9]`. Since s and t and 0 through 9 are all word characters there cannot be a word boundary between them. Also you have an unescaped closing parenthesis. This `@"\d+\(\$[st][0-9]\)"` will work.

If your operand list is simply delimited by commas, then split the string on commas and verify each one

```
string command = "$t7,248($t2)";

string [] operands = command.Split(new Char [] {','});
```

and your regexes need to be anchored at the beginning and end, like this

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(source, @"^\$t[0-9]$"))
    return OperandType.Temporary;
if (Regex.IsMatch(source, @"^\$s[0-9]$"))
    return OperandType.Store;
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks the first on does not work but he memory regex does. I have decided to check whether it ends with a comma before testing the regex. This will make it easier to exclude the last param as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This expression might work:

> ,$

Comment: didn't work. tried @"\$t[0-9],$"  not sure if that what u meant

Comment: Try escaping the comma. "\$t[0-9]\,$"

Comment: Comma isn't a regex metacharacter and doesn't need escaping. I think the problem is that the comma isn't at the end of the string.